# Number of figure and description, between them "-"

Tags: captions

I have the following problem, I have a figure with its number and description like this:

[image]

but I wish to delete the after the "2":

[image]

In order to have a thing like this:

> Figure3.2 - Simple tables part one

I use this code:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.75 ]{./imageName.png}
\caption{Simple table part 2}
\label{fig:exp:Lc3f3}   
\end{figure}
```

Have you some idea in order to replace this point with "-" in such away to separate them?

Comment: Could you please turn your code fragment into a compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) by adding the documentclass and the relevant packages? In order to obtain the desired result, you might be interested in the `labelsep` option of the `caption` package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `caption` helps  for that:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float, caption}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelsep=endash}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{chapter}{3}
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.5 ]{traccia-table}
\caption{Simple table part 1}
\label{fig:exp:Lc3f3}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]